# linux bash shell: search for files containing partially-known word sequence

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

How can I recursively search a directory for files containing a partially-known word sequence like this:

... target1 <any_word> <any_wor> target2 ...

This sequence might appear anywhere in any line. I know there will be exactly 2 words between target1 and target2 but I don't know what they might be, and I don't want to match if there are more or less than 2 words between targets.

A grep , awk, or sed solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -rlE 'target1 \w+ \w+ target2' .
```

Caveat - this only works if the "sentence" is not split over two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:

```
grep -rl 'target1.*target2' .
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'target1.*target2' {} +
```

adjusting the regex if needed

Comment: This will match ANY number of words (or characters, as it were) between the two targets, not just two words.